# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast when getting multipile fields Hibernate Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I fresh on spring technology and hibernate. Some days ago i create query getting all rows from table using repository. Today i was try get 2 fields from database. When i try read data form result list i getting `Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast`. This is my enity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cms")
public class Cms implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1759832392332242809L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id_page;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    private String content;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date modifyDate;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int createBy;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int modifedBy;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean inMenu;
    public Cms(Long id_page, String title, String content, Date createDate,
            Date modifyDate) {
        this.id_page = id_page;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
        this.createBy = 1;
        this.modifedBy = 1;
        this.inMenu = true;
    }
//getters setters to string
}
```

Repository

```
public interface CmsRepository extends Repository<Cms, Long>{
    @Query("Select u.id_page,u.title from Cms u")
List<Cms> getMenu();
}
```

And takie this on controller

```
List<Cms> menus= cmsservice.menuAll();
System.out.println(menus.get(0).toString()); //error
```

Some one can explain me on example what is bad and how can fix this, this will helpfull for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because you are retrieving individual properties - not the entire Cms Object.

I would use an instance of Query for this:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("Select u.id_page,u.title from Cms u");
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
for(Object[] elements: results){
Long id = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(elements[0]));
String title  = String.valueOf(elements[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT NEW org.agoncal.javaee7.CustomerDTO(c.firstName, c.lastName, c.address.
street1)
FROM Customer c